# vim-cmake-project error: perl not found

Tags: vim

I'm trying to install [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4279). I installed the libfile-find-rule-perl yet when I run vim it gives me an error saying, "Error: perl not found." Perl is installed! How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vim installation was not installed with perl.

If you look at the first couple of lines of the plugin you find.

```
if !has('perl')
  echo 'Error: perl not found'
  finish
else
```

`has('perl')` checks to see if vim has the perl feature. Since you see the output of the if statement you do not have the perl feature.

To fix this error recompile vim with perl enabled.

Comment: So there is no debian package I can install with perl enabled?

Comment: what OS (as in what package manager) are you running? Most likely you can find a package that has perl enabled.

Comment: Try `apt-get vim-nox`, vim-gnome or vim-gtk packages. I'm not really sure what packages have what enabled.

Comment: Alright, I install vim-gnome and it appears to work now. Thank you very much!

Comment: As a note the way you can check if a feature is installed is by doing `vim --version` and checking to see if a `+` or `-` is next to the features name. `+` means included `-` means excluded.